# Перемещение по игровому полю ( двумерному массиву ) через указатели (с++)

Tags: c++

У меня есть следующее задание, нужно создать следующую игру в консоли: Есть прямоугольное поле в противоположных углах находятся игроки, задача такова: нужно быстрее другого игрока дойти до противоположного угла. На карте есть скрытые клетки, наступая на которые игрок пропускает ход. Подскажите, как можно реализовать перемещение игроков. Понимаю, что через указатели, но не пойму как. Из готового у меня есть считанная с файла карта, которая хранится в двумерном динамическом массиве, по типу этой:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 8 4 0 0 0 4 0 0 4 0 0 4 0 1
1 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 1
1 0 4 0 0 0 4 4 0 0 0 0 4 0 1
1 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 1
1 0 4 0 0 0 4 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 4 0 4 0 0 0 4 0 4 0 4 1
1 4 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 4 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 4 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1


1- границы
0- пустая клетка
4 - клетка-пропуск хода
8 - первый игрок
9 - второй игрок
```

Следовательно, если первый игрок дойдет в точку старта второго, то он победит.
Вывожу на экран эту карту сверяя цифру в массиве и исходя из ее значения вывожу нужный символ:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно сделать?

---

Подскажите, задумка правильная, или уже заведомо бракованная? Но проблема в том, что я не знаю как тогда перемещаться вниз и вверх, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
gamer1 = &mas[1][1]; // размещаю указатели на места старта игроков
gamer2 = &mas[n - 2][m - 2];
cout << gamer1 << endl;
while (gamer1 != &mas[n - 2][m - 2] && gamer2 != &mas[1][1])
{
    if (skip1 == 0) // проверка на пропуск хода
    {
        cout << "Ход первого игрока" << endl;
        cout << "1) Вправо" << endl;
        cout << "2) Вниз" << endl;
        cin >> move;
        if (move == 1)
        {
            *gamer1 = 0;
            gamer1++;
            if (*gamer1 == 4)
            {
                skip1++;
            }
            *gamer1 = 8;
            system("cls");
            printMap(map, m, n);
        }
        else if (move == 2) // как реализовать передвижение вверх и вниз?
        {

        }
    }
    else 
    {
       cout << "Пропуск хода!" << endl;
       skip1--;
    }
} // это только начало кода,  просто хотел узнать, так нужно делать или нет.
```

Comment: Не нужен, ни двухмерный массив, ни указатели. Нужен одномерный массив и индекс в нем.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто завести две переменные gamer1 и gamer2 и чекать их состояние на доске.
Есть два пути:

1. Каждый ход заново рендерить массив вставляя игроков и пропуск ходов
2. Запоминать oldState игроков и изменять их по ходу движения
   Первое сделать легче, но второе по памяти займет меньше

Comment: Попробую сделать, просто я плохо понимаю эту тему с указателями, осталось понять как это все реализовать теперь) В любом случае спасибо